# SQL suppress no results

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, export-to-excel, jobs

I wrote a query that pulls data if a specific permission is granted to any active user.  I created an SSIS package and I plan to create a job that drops the export to a share once a month.

Most of the time this report will be blank as no user is allowed to have this permission.  I'm trying to avoid having a folder full of blank reports.  Any suggestions/solutions to only have this report generate if there are actual results?

Is there any control I can put in the query, package or job?

Comment: You mean an SSIS package?  If so, the answer is most likely to be found in there.

Answer (score 0):

Again, assuming you mean SSIS package, the answer is a conditional split.  I've linked to a good post that compares different methods for accomplishing no empty files.
[Prevent empty files at destination](https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/how-to-prevent-ssis-package-creating-empty-flat-file-at-the-destination/)

Comment: Sorry, yes an SSIS Package.  I think adding a condition instead of a conditional split might work better for my particular situation.  I will try both and see which one works better.  Thank you paulbarin for the ray of hope!